# jQuery AJAX jsonp calling intervally cause memory leak

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, memory-leaks

I try to intervally ajax calling using jQuery ajax function using setTimeout() in ajax complete callback, but it cause memory leak.

I think everytime callAJAX is called, some ajax object in jQuery is created and there are some recursive reference, so created object cannot be free.

What can I do for avoiding memory leak?

```
var count = 0;
var AJAX = $.ajax;
function callAJAX() {
    AJAX({
        url: "http://192.168.137.1:8080/data.json",
        dataType: "JSONP",
        jsonpCallback: "abc",
        success: function(data) {
            document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data, null, 4) + '<br>' + count;
        },
        error: function(e) {
            console.error(e);
        },
        complete: function() {            
            count++;
            setTimeout(callAJAX, 1000); // It maybe cause memory leak
        }
    });
}
```

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: what are the contents of data?

Comment: data is simple JSON object like this: {"data":12345}

Comment: if you don't do anything on the success and error callbacks, do you still have a memory leak?

Comment: @jorar91 Yes, it also have memory leak.

Comment: can you provide a demo?

Comment: is this accurate @Park https://jsfiddle.net/hnd46bfo/8/ ?

Comment: @jorar91 Yes, this code is I used.